# VBA-Excel 2010 Macro Error "memeber or data method not found"

Tags: excel, vba

I know this is a super generic error but I am new to VBA / Macros and cant get past this.

I have an and excel workbook that has data I need to copy to another excel workbook.
The excel workbook that the data is copied to is on a network share and will be written to frequently.

here is my macro code:

```
Sub export()
Dim exportFile As String
Dim importSheet As String
Dim rowData As String

exportFile = "\\<server>\spd\_Spec_ParaData\data_import.xlsx"
importSheet = "OutPutValues"
importRange = "A2:ZZ2"

' Get the row from the workbook that we are running in
rowData = Workbooks().Worksheets(importSheet).Range(importRange)

' Not sure if this will work, or always overwrite the last row. May need to be .Row+1
newRow = Workbooks(exportFile).Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

exportRange = "A" & (newRow + 1) & ":ZZ" & (newRow + 1)

' Assuming Workbooks() gets the current workbook.
Workbooks(exportFile).Sheets(exportSheet).Range(exportRange) = Workbooks().Sheets(importSheet).Range(importRange)

End Sub
```

My error is poping up on the rowData=Workbooks(exportFile).**Worksheets**

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you,
Jennifer

Comment: it probably means that the object "Workbooks(exportFile)" doesn't exist, because the string "exportFile" that you pass as address of the workbook doesn't point to any Excel workbook.

Comment: Try to detail a bit more the problem if you wanna get help. I'd suggest: 1.Create a new macro and put only `exportFile = "\\yourPath"`, `myWorkbook = Workbooks(exportFile)`; 2. Run the macro; 3. Edit your question with the error you get by doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your code with the following modifications, I'm just opening the workbook and referencing the worksheet (I guess the problem is that). I'm closing the workbook straight after.

```
Sub export()
Dim exportFile As String
Dim importSheet As String
Dim rowData As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

exportFile = "\\<server>\spd\_Spec_ParaData\data_import.xlsx"
importSheet = "OutPutValues"
importRange = "A2:ZZ2"

'Open your workbook and point to your spreadsheet    
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(exportFile)
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(importSheet)    

' Get the row from the workbook that we are running in
rowData = wb.ws.Range(importRange)

' Not sure if this will work, or always overwrite the last row. May need to be .Row+1
newRow = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

exportRange = "A" & (newRow + 1) & ":ZZ" & (newRow + 1)

'NOTE: consider definying the variable "exportSheet", I will do it just for example purpose
Dim exportSheet As String: exportSheet = "InputValues"
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(exportSheet)

' Assuming Workbooks() gets the current workbook.
wb.ws2.Range(exportRange) = wb.ws1.Range(importRange)
wb.Close

End Sub
```